# What is the equivalent of JS 'appendChild' in Flutter to add a button class to a specific container?

Tags: flutter, dart

Im currently working on an app where buttons should appear depending on how close you are to an animal in a zoo. So you walk around and when an animal is closer than 5 meters, a button should appear with his name on it.

I already implemented that the app can recognize where you are and if an animal is close to you. I also already have a class with the button that should appear. What Im trying to do now it that my methode is adding this button class to a specific container in the code, similar to the JS command

```
const document = getElementById("0")
document.body.appendChild(SelectButton());
```

Maybe you get the point by that example. I already tried a bit around with Keys but I dont think that I fully unterstood them by now.